# name 'sift_down' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

```
class Heap():

    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

    def add(self, elem_with_priority):
        self.array.append(elem_with_priority)
        sift_up(len(self.array) - 1)

    def build_heap(self):
        for idx in reversed(range(int(len(self.array) / 2 - 1))):
            sift_down(idx)

    def sift_down(self, idx):
        left, right = 2 * idx + 1, 2 * idx + 2
        largest = idx
        if left < len(self.array) and self.array[left][1] > self.array[idx][1]:
            largest = left
        if right < len(self.array) and self.array[right][1] > self.array[idx][1]:
            largest = right
        if largest != idx:
            self.array[idx], self.array[largest] = self.array[largest], self.array[idx]
            sift_down(largest)

    def sift_up(self, idx):
        while idx > 0:
            parent = int(idx - 1) / 2
            if self.array[idx][1] <= self.array[parent][1]:
                return
            self.array[idx], self.array[parent] = self.array[parent], self.array[idx]
            idx = parent

a = Heap([(1,2), (3,4), (5,4), (13,3), (175, 80), (22,17)])

a.build_heap()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Функции `sift_down` и ей подобные объявлены не глобально, а внутри класса, поэтому нужно их вызывать от текущего объекта `self`:

```
self.sift_down(idx)
```

Это касается и `sift_up`